# SignalStrength has no method getRsrq in api 25

Tags: android, telephony, lte

When I use `api 25` as my compile sdk some methods from class `SignalStrength` are getting marked as hidden. 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/012aX.png)

How to deal with it if I need to use `SignalStrength.getLteRsrp()` but it is hidden?